# tf checkin a specific folder

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, checkin

in the "checkin" command documentation of Visual Studio it says:

> Check in a change to a single item without using the Check In dialog box
>
> `c:\code\SiteApp\Main>tf checkin program.cs /noprompt`

How can I checkin a specific folder?

Like that:
`tf checkin path/path/path -comment:"some comment"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tf checkin /recursive` , it will check in everything under a given directory.

You have two ways to checkin a specific folder: (Navigate to your workspace first, eg, My workspace mapped to `E:\andy\0718\maven`)

**1. Specify folder path directly:** (Add a new folder "**0719**" with *.txt files to test that)

```
tf checkin E:\andy\0718\maven\0719 /comment:"0719" /recursive /noprompt
```

**2. Navigate to the specific directory (folder), then check in the files in current folder:**

```
cd 07192

tf checkin /comment:"07192 test" /noprompt
```

**Note:** In above example, I added new folder "0719" and "07192" with *.txt files to test that, you can using the tf checkin command directly to checkin your existing folders.
[image]

[image]

Comment: @Peter Shershov Have you resolved your issue by above workaround? any update for this?

Comment: Hey! thanks for the answer!
I resolved it by myself but your answer is correct.
I'm using a mac so the syntax is a bit different:
tf checkin 'path/path' -comment:'some comment' -recursive.