# Checkin solution via command line using tf.exe

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs

I know you can checkin specific files with tf.exe, but is there a way to specify and checkin an entire solution?

Answer (score 0):

After some more searching, I found this question: [tf checkin a specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45162328/tf-checkin-a-specific-folder)

Following a similar approach I was able to check in the contents of my solution using this command:

`tf checkin "C:\My\Solution\Directory" /recursive`